# Foundation 5 top-bar dropdown menu randomly doesn't work, but then works after refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I have a dropdown menu in my rails app (rails 4, ruby 2) that uses Foundation 5. Most of the time the dropdown menu works fine, but sometimes it (seemingly randomly) doesn't drop-down. I have tried it using both "hover" and "clickable" and got the same random breakdowns. Any time it hasn't worked, simply refreshing the page has solved the problem, but this is still a problem for users that I would like to avoid. Any suggestions?

This code is in `views/layouts/_header.html.erb` and is rendered in `application.html.erb`:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="is_hover: false">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><%= link_to 'What Key Am I In?', root_path %></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar">Menu</li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">All Keys</a></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'All Chords', chords_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'All Notes', notes_path %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <% if current_user.nil? %>
          <li><%= link_to 'Sign up!', new_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% else %>
          <a href="#"><%= current_user.username %></a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><%= link_to 'View profile', current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Chords Pending Approval', chords_pending_approval_path %>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned off Turbolinks and it seems to be working so far. Looks like this may have been what was causing the issue, which isn't that surprising as I have run into issues with things not working as expected because of Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following code after your foundation.js include and do you have any other javascript plugins that you are using?  I have had this issue before with a JQuery image slider and fixed it by adding and putting my code between the braces.  Hope this is some what useful if not I will do some more research into this and can hopefully help out!

```
     $(window).load(function() {}
```

You should have this at the bottom of your file as well.

```
 <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
 <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, but I have this in my `application.js` file: //= require foundation

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

Comment: Ok well I forgot you were using rails, you actually shouldn't need that line in your js.  As long as foundation.js and foundation.topbar.js are in your app/assets/javascripts and your foundation.css is in your app/assets/stylesheets folder rails should automatically load them.  Now as far as your actual problem I will make a quick app using foundation when I get the time and see if we can get this solved.  Also note you only need the regular files, no minified versions as rails will minify them for you.

Comment: Great, thanks! Still having this problem with the topbar, and I am now having it with the link-dropdowns that I have since added (it happens at the same time as the topbar having issues, both of which are resolved by refreshing the page), which leads me to believe that click listeners are not getting added correctly. Thanks again!